# Tensorflow is working in command prompt but not in Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I have installed tensor flow in my 64 bit system using Window OS using `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`. Now I can able to work using tensorflow in my command prompt.

But while I'm trying to use it in my Anaconda ,Spyder (Python 2.7) I'm getting error message in `import tensorflow as tf` statement. It is saying `No module named tensorflow`. I'm new to python & tensorflow. Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new conda environment. Your steps to create one with python=3.5 is **correct**. if you do not do this then you will have errors.
Once you have created that environment make sure you enter it: `activate envName` for example. You should get something like:

`(envName) C:/> _`

Then you should be able to install using `pip install tensorflow`

Once that has installed then run `conda list` to ensure that your conda env is happy that Tensorflow is installed. Then test it out by running

```

```
python
>>>import tensorflow as tf
```

```

Tensorflow on Windows will **NOT** work on anything but Python 3.5 at time of writing. Please remember to activate you conda environment by typing `activate yourenvName` and ensure that your environment is 3.5 when you create it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by uninstalling ipython and installing jupyter within the environment.

```
source activate myenv
conda uninstall ipython
conda install jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

installs tensorflow for Python3, and you want to use it in Python2. Try to

```
  pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

For more info read [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)

Comment: Hi ingvar, Thanks for the reply.I want to upgrade python 2 to python 3.5 in anaconda.I tried conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda statement. But still I'm getting same error. Will this tensor for work with Python 3.6 version? That is the version available in continuam websit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with anaconda, so I can only recommend to reinstall tensorflow again on new (with python 35) anaconda distribution

Comment: @RLearner you can't just upgrade Python 2 to 3. Both are different major version. Python 2 and 3 got different installation method.